# No longer able to create a bacpac: SQL70015: Deprecated feature 'String literals as column aliases' is not supported on SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We have encountered a critical error today - we are no longer able to create bacpac files of our live Azure production databases. Everything was working up until now, and suddenly we've started encountering the following error:

**Error encountered during the service operation. Could not extract package from specified database. Error SQL70015: Deprecated feature 'String literals as column aliases' is not supported on SQL Azure.**

We have a complex database schema which has been deployed live to Azure for over a year. We are relying on daily bacpacs are our only backup strategy - need help to figure out how to resume making bacpacs.

Answer (score 7):

well I fell your pain... the answer here is: Replace your schema...There's no other way...
Instead of `'Column Name'` use `[Column Name]`... instead of `Select CryptColumnA 'Column A' from myTable` use `Select CryptColumnA as [Column A] from myTable` and so forth...

Comment: I agree with both of you. This was a crappy breaking change for them to have made without making sure everybody was aware of this and this is likely your only solution - "fix it". Really unfortunate situation. I really hope you didn't have production code depending on this! If so, I'd go check your stored procs/functions/views now (that's likely what's in the backup causing this error).

Comment: How do we go about doing this? We have a large business database with hundreds of tables, and there is no single create script for it, because it's versioned. How do we discover which columns need to be altered? Also, changing the database schema is challenging because we do it only when we roll out a new version of the software. We are in production, bigtime, with dozens of databases and live customers using them!

Comment: @davidair Management Studio 2012 has a feature called "Script Database" that can help you! just right click the database->Script Database As

Comment: So what exactly do I need to fix? Sprocs? UDFs? Views? Indexed Views? I tried creating a small database with one table and one UDF, it bacpac'ed alright:

CREATE FUNCTION GetNames() RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
(SELECT Name 'Person Name' from Test)

Our production database has almost 2000 sprocs, and about 200 views... it's going to be a royal pain to review!

Comment: I bet you need to look at sprocs, functions, and/or views. Just script it out via SSMS and use a regex to find offending code/schemas. While this may be a pita, it shouldn't be too terrible. You shouldn't need any data scripted. Ultimately, I've yet to find documentation on this change hitting yesterday/today so I'm guessing right now.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post to see an offending example. This appears to have been deprecated with SQL2008. http://bobthegoblin.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/sql-azure-migration-errors-solutions/

Comment: To be honest, I am really not sure how I'd even write the regex to find the offending statements. Looking for "select '" doesn't do it. Also, our database has been in production for over a year, and bacpac'ed alright. This is a very old blog post. Something is very suspicious, but the error message does not tell me which object is actually causing the problem.

Comment: Just filed an Azure support ticket - will see if the MS folks provide any additional clarifications/insight.

Comment: It was deprecated with SQL 2008. Deprecation doesn't mean, "It stops working now". It means "It will stop working at some point in the future". Today is most certainly a point in the future. Perhaps they upgraded the bacpac validator last night and added this new rule based on a 5-year-old deprecation.

Comment: The problem with Azure, as opposed to the regular SQL Server, is that it gets upgraded on you without any warning. Code using a deprecated feature could be very painful to fix, but when you control the environment, it can be an explicit decision ("we're upgrading to SQL Server 2012 SP1 and we understand that some things will break", or "we will postpone the upgrade because it will require us to invest two weeks of dev time to migrate our code and we cannot afford it right now"). Doing something that transparently breaks production systems is a "no-no" in my book.

Comment: I agreed with that way back in my original comment on here. This have been a very well-communicated change with months of warning going into it. That said, you probably shouldn't have pushed a several-year-old deprecation to Azure. Azure is *not* the right platform for technologies that was last allowed 8 years ago.

Comment: @Jaxidian How can anyone say "without making sure everybody was aware of this" - do you want a postcard and a phone call in addition to the [list of deprecated features that have been announced since 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/bb510662(v=sql.100))? I believe it was in the 2005 documentation as well, but that documentation has been retired. [People have also blogged about it](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases).

Answer (score 0):

We have filed a support ticket with Microsoft and the issue was acknowledged as a bug. We only had a problem with bacpac export, not import - and apparently it was due to a SQL Azure change which hardened some of the export validations.

To make the long story short, the issue has been fixed by Microsoft and we are no longer experiencing the problem - and that is without any schema changes on our end.