# SQL is rounding my decimal on cast

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, decimal, converters

I'm using SQL Server 2005. The datatype is `varchar`.  I'm trying to convert numbers like

```
1250000
```

to

```
1.25
```

within the SQL query and drop the trailing zeroes. I have tried a number of things with no success - have run into 'trim is not a function', etc.

Here's what I currently have, in each iteration that I have attempted.

```
select top 30 
    var1, var2, var3, var4, 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), (var5 / 1000000)) as 'Number' 
from 
    databasetable 
where 
    var1 = x 

select top 30 
    var1, var2, var3, var4, 
    cast((var5 / 1000000) as decimal(6,2)) as 'Number' 
from 
    databasetable 
where 
    var1 = x
```

Both queries above are rounding to the nearest million, i.e. 1250000 becomes 1.00, etc. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Changing decimal to numeric did not help either.

Comment: Would like to add the the first query string worked fine in SQL server 2000; I'm having problems due to a recent upgrade.

Comment: Instead of commenting, you should edit your question with the relevant information.

Comment: can you try - cast(var5  as decimal(10,2))/ 1000000

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Don't store **numerical values** in a `varchar` column!

Comment: Yosi, that was close.  Now I get 1.250000000 and etc.

Comment: @user2697262 select (CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), '125000') / 1000000) as 'Number'         
This is the way you should do it (using the same way you used). First convert to decimal and then divide. And another important point: (6,2) 6 is the total size (including decimals), in that case you need to increase that number there.

Answer (score 4):

@marc_s is absolutely right - [***stop storing numbers as strings!***](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

That said, you're a victim of integer math. Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), (var5 / 1000000.0))
```

Since you stored numbers as strings, SQL Server may try to perform this calculation with non-numeric data before applying the filter, so you can say:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(var5) = 1 THEN var5 END / 1000000.0))
```

[[Note that this isn't perfect either](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html).]

If this doesn't work then you've got some bad data. If the following *does* work but yields too many decimal places:

```
select 
    var1, ...,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), var5) / 1000000 as [Number]
```

Then try wrapping it with an extra convert:

```
select 
    var1, ...,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), var5) / 1000000) as [Number]
```

That all said, why can't you format this number in the presentation layer?

Also, please don't use `'single quotes'` for column aliases ... [this syntax is deprecated in some forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284012/no-longer-able-to-create-a-bacpac-sql70015-deprecated-feature-string-literals), and it incorrectly makes your column alias look like a string (IMHO). Use `[square brackets]` or just avoid using keywords as aliases.

Comment: That produced [Err] 22003 - [SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

I know not to store numbers as strings - my hands are tied.  Not my DB; I'm just the guy trying to fix it.  :(  Much appreciating all of the suggestions.

Comment: Updated answer, SQL Server is probably applying the calculation before the filter, and trying to divide garbage data.

Comment: Hmm.  The fix has the same error - [Err] 22003 - [SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

Comment: @user2697262 And /1000000 works? Can you narrow down the sample data to a value that causes the problem?

Comment: So far, this is the closest to what I need - I just can't seem to get rid of the trailing zeroes.

select top 30 var1, var2, var3, var4, cast(var5 as decimal(10,2)) / 1000000 as [Number] from databasetable where etc etc etc.

The original number in the DB will be something like 1250000, and the above turns it into 1.250000000.

Comment: How about now, using 10,2 instead of 6,2?

Comment: Aaron, you're my new hero.  CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), var5) / 1000000) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure without know you're exact platform, but my guess would be its truncating it to an int.  I would try converting `var5` and `10000000` before doing the math.  Something like

```
// NOTE, I have not tried this code
CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), (CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), var5) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,2), 1000000)))
```

Comment: This one produces [Err] 22003 - [SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select convert(decimal(5,2),convert(decimal(10,3),var5) / 1000000) where isnumeric(var5)=1
```

Comment: This one produced error:  [Err] 22003 - [SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    ColA VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ColA) VALUES ('1250000');
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ColA) VALUES ('125');
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ColA) VALUES ('12');
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ColA) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ColA) VALUES ('');
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ColA) VALUES ('e5');
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ColA) VALUES ('0x34abc');

SELECT  *, 
        w.ColB / 1000000.0 AS ColC,
        CONVERT(NUMERIC(4,2), w.ColB / 1000000.0) AS ColD, -- The result is rounded to 2 decimals; You should change default precision (4) and scale (2)
        STR(w.ColB / 1000000.0, 5, 2) AS ColE, -- The result is rounded to 2 decimals; You should change default lenght (5) and scale (2)       
        w.ColB * 1.0 / POWER(10, ColLength-1) AS ColF
FROM
(
    SELECT  *,
            CASE 
                -- It assumes that all values are INT[egers] without sign (+/-)
                WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', RTRIM(LTRIM(v.ColA))) = 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(v.ColA)) BETWEEN 1 AND 11 THEN CONVERT(INT, v.ColA)
                ELSE NULL -- It returns NULL if the value cann't be converted to INT
            END AS ColB,
            LEN(LTRIM(v.ColA)) AS ColLength
    FROM    @MyTable v
) w
```

Results:

```
ColA    ColB    ColLength ColC        ColD ColE  ColF
------- ------- --------- ----------- ---- ----- --------------
1250000 1250000 7         1.250000000 1.25  1.25 1.250000000000
125     125     3         0.000125000 0.00  0.00 1.250000000000
12      12      2         0.000012000 0.00  0.00 1.200000000000
1       1       1         0.000001000 0.00  0.00 1.000000000000
        NULL    0         NULL        NULL NULL  NULL
e5      NULL    2         NULL        NULL NULL  NULL
0x34abc NULL    7         NULL        NULL NULL  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Realise that this is an old post, but I've had the same issue today trying to convert a 3 digit int into a decimal, i.e. 422 into 4.22

```
SELECT CONVERT(Decimal(10, 2), 422/100) returns 4.00

SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2) 422/100.0) returns 4.22
```