# difference between dates in hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time

I have searched many of the threads and cant find the answer I need. I have two datetime columns:

```
BOOKDATIME                BOOKDATIME_OFF 
2013-06-01 12:14:00.000   2013-06-03 07:09:00.000
```

What I want to do is to just show the total hour and minute difference between the two dates.

When I use:

```
CONVERT(TIME, BOOKDATIME_OFF - BOOKDATIME) 
                  AS HourMinuteSecond
```

I get the error message: Cannot call methods on time

Comment: You could use [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Comment: Subtracting two `datetime` values and converting to `time` is permissible in SQL Server.  Can you show the entire query that generates the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATEDIFF(HH,BOOKDATIME, BOOKDATIME_OFF)
```

Comment: *Please type out `HOUR` explicitly instead of saving two whole characters and typing `HH` - [shorthands cause confusion](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF()` and division/modulus division to get difference in total Hours/Minutes:

```
SELECT Hours = DATEDIFF(Minute,'2013-06-01 12:14:00.000','2013-06-03 07:09:00.000')/60
      ,Minutes = DATEDIFF(Minute,'2013-06-01 12:14:00.000','2013-06-03 07:09:00.000')%60
```

If the `DATETIME` fields are always less than a day apart then you can also subtract the datetime's and cast as time:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETDATE()
       ,@date2 DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE,25,GETDATE())
SELECT CAST(@date2 - @date AS TIME)
```

Comment: Kudos for adding the hour difference, but the calculation is wrong (it has one extra hour, because the datediff calulates hours difference between '09:59:59' and '10:00:00' as 1). You should take the minute difference and divide by 60 instead

Comment: *Also, please don't use `'single quote column aliases'` - this syntax is deprecated in some forms, and also makes those aliases look like string literals. `[square brackets]` are much preferable, IMHO, and only when they're actually necessary.*

Comment: The "cast as time" part will broke when the difference is bigger than 23:59:59.99999999 hours (so it won't work on OP's example)

Comment: Just noticed that, seems like a caveat to include rather than a change to be made.

Comment: @AaronBertrand not sure I agree with that, I like the way a single-quote alias sticks out in my code, never seemed to confuse my peers, but will think on it.

Comment: @GoatCO well maybe [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284012/no-longer-able-to-create-a-bacpac-sql70015-deprecated-feature-string-literals) and consider that `SELECT 'foo' = 'bar', 'bar' AS 'foo';` might not be confusing to you, but it sure can be confusing to others (and is really hard for me to read).

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote? It came after updating question to its current state, so curious.